# Twitter API using curl in PHP "direct_messages/new.json"

Tags: php, curl, twitter, oauth

I am using the oauth library to use twitter API for sending the **Direct Message** to user using curl,but getting the "{"errors":[{"code":215,"message":"Bad Authentication data."}]}".

If i use terminal for curl then it works fine, but getting error while sending through PHP.

```
    <pre>
        <?php
            error_reporting(1);
            require("twitterOauth/autoload.php");

            use Abraham\TwitterOAuth\TwitterOAuth;

            $text = "Hello, How Are U?";

            $headers = array(
            'Authorization: OAuth oauth_consumer_key="OAuth oauth_consumer_key", 
            oauth_nonce="oauth_nonce", 
            oauth_signature="oauth_signature", 
            oauth_signature_method="HMAC-SHA1", 
            oauth_timestamp="1439978004", 
            oauth_token="oauth_token", 
            oauth_version="1.0"'
            );


            // Get cURL resource
            $curl = curl_init();
            // Set some options - we are passing in a useragent too here
            curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
                CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => 1,
                CURLOPT_URL => 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/direct_messages/new.json',
                CURLOPT_POST => 1,
                CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => 0,
                CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS => array(
                    'text' => urlencode($text),
                    'screen_name' => 'screen_name'
                ),$headers
            ));

            // Send the request & save response to $resp
                $resp = curl_exec($curl);
                print_r('Curl error: ' . curl_error($resp));
                echo '<pre>'; print_r($resp); die;
            // Close request to clear up some resources
            curl_close($curl);
        ?>
    </pre>
```

Comment: Where you able to resolve this issue?
I'm encountering the same problem.